# 6GB GPU memory available, but tensorflow.keras only uses 3

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Can anyone tell me why im running out of memory? My GPU has 6GB of dedicated. In the start keras only wanted to see 3GB. But after forcing it to see 5.5, it still refuses to go above 3, and produces this error:

```
22022-05-26 20:09:34.753023: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:290] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.32GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-05-26 20:09:34.753167: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:290] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.32GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-05-26 20:09:35.198911: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:290] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.56GiB with freed_by_count=0. The caller indicates that this is not a failure, but this may mean that there could be performance gains if more memory were available.
2022-05-26 20:09:35.199028: W tensorflow/core/kernels/gpu_utils.cc:50] Failed to allocate memory for convolution redzone checking; skipping this check. This is benign and only means that we won't check cudnn for out-of-bounds reads and writes. This message will only be printed once.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.505510: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:479] Allocator (GPU_0_bfc) ran out of memory trying to allocate 1.55GiB (rounded to 1661337600)requested by op zero_dce/StatefulPartitionedCall/StatefulPartitionedCall/model/conv2d_2/Conv2D
If the cause is memory fragmentation maybe the environment variable 'TF_GPU_ALLOCATOR=cuda_malloc_async' will improve the situation.
Current allocation summary follows.
Current allocation summary follows.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.505656: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1027] BFCAllocator dump for GPU_0_bfc
2022-05-26 20:09:47.506718: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (256):  Total Chunks: 25, Chunks in use: 25. 6.2KiB allocated for chunks. 6.2KiB in use in bin. 960B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.508009: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (512):  Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.508351: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (1024):         Total Chunks: 2, Chunks in use: 1. 2.5KiB allocated for chunks. 1.2KiB in use in bin. 1.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.508696: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (2048):         Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 3.5KiB allocated for chunks. 3.5KiB in use in bin. 3.4KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.509250: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (4096):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.509749: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (8192):         Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.510290: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (16384):        Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.510665: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (32768):        Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 3. 129.2KiB allocated for chunks. 129.2KiB in use in bin. 108.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.511011: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (65536):        Total Chunks: 4, Chunks in use: 3. 324.2KiB allocated for chunks. 216.2KiB in use in bin. 198.0KiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.511337: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (131072):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.511696: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (262144):       Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.512012: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (524288):       Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 0. 692.2KiB allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.512342: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (1048576):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.512667: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (2097152):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.512996: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (4194304):      Total Chunks: 1, Chunks in use: 1. 5.72MiB allocated for chunks. 5.72MiB in use in bin. 5.72MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.513321: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (8388608):      Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.513648: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (16777216):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.513968: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (33554432):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.514280: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (67108864):     Total Chunks: 0, Chunks in use: 0. 0B allocated for chunks. 0B in use in bin. 0B client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.514616: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (134217728):    Total Chunks: 4, Chunks in use: 3. 594.14MiB allocated for chunks. 445.61MiB in use in bin. 445.61MiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.514937: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1034] Bin (268435456):    Total Chunks: 3, Chunks in use: 2. 4.25GiB allocated for chunks. 3.09GiB in use in bin. 3.09GiB client-requested in use in bin.
2022-05-26 20:09:47.515309: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1050] Bin for 1.55GiB was 256.00MiB, Chunk State:
2022-05-26 20:09:47.515636: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1056]   Size: 1.15GiB | Requested Size: 5.72MiB | in_use: 0 | bin_num: 20, prev:   Size: 1.55GiB | Requested Size: 1.55GiB | in_use: 1 | bin_num: -1
2022-05-26 20:09:47.516110: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1063] Next region of size 5190451200
2022-05-26 20:09:47.516933: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000000 of size 256 next 1
2022-05-26 20:09:47.517305: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000100 of size 1280 next 2
2022-05-26 20:09:47.517655: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000600 of size 256 next 3
2022-05-26 20:09:47.517962: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000700 of size 256 next 4
2022-05-26 20:09:47.518281: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000800 of size 256 next 5
2022-05-26 20:09:47.518611: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000900 of size 256 next 6
2022-05-26 20:09:47.518920: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000a00 of size 256 next 9
2022-05-26 20:09:47.519250: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000b00 of size 256 next 10
2022-05-26 20:09:47.519577: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000c00 of size 256 next 57
2022-05-26 20:09:47.519891: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000d00 of size 256 next 55
2022-05-26 20:09:47.520227: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000e00 of size 256 next 16
2022-05-26 20:09:47.520550: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e000f00 of size 256 next 18
2022-05-26 20:09:47.520874: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001000 of size 256 next 19
2022-05-26 20:09:47.521505: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001100 of size 256 next 58
2022-05-26 20:09:47.523840: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001200 of size 256 next 24
2022-05-26 20:09:47.524446: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001300 of size 256 next 25
2022-05-26 20:09:47.524756: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001400 of size 256 next 26
2022-05-26 20:09:47.525078: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001500 of size 256 next 28
2022-05-26 20:09:47.525408: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e001600 of size 256 next 29
2022-05-26 20:09:47.525755: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 70e001700 of size 708864 next 40
2022-05-26 20:09:47.526092: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0ae800 of size 256 next 61
2022-05-26 20:09:47.526434: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0ae900 of size 256 next 62
2022-05-26 20:09:47.526775: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0aea00 of size 256 next 51
2022-05-26 20:09:47.527092: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0aeb00 of size 256 next 42
2022-05-26 20:09:47.527404: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0aec00 of size 39936 next 44
2022-05-26 20:09:47.527730: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0b8800 of size 256 next 43
2022-05-26 20:09:47.528052: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0b8900 of size 36864 next 46
2022-05-26 20:09:47.528375: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0c1900 of size 256 next 45
2022-05-26 20:09:47.528743: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0c1a00 of size 256 next 48
2022-05-26 20:09:47.529089: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 70e0c1b00 of size 110592 next 50
2022-05-26 20:09:47.529432: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0dcb00 of size 73984 next 52
2022-05-26 20:09:47.529935: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0eec00 of size 55552 next 54
2022-05-26 20:09:47.530519: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 70e0fc500 of size 1280 next 59
2022-05-26 20:09:47.530843: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0fca00 of size 3584 next 60
2022-05-26 20:09:47.531200: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e0fd800 of size 73728 next 41
2022-05-26 20:09:47.531535: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e10f800 of size 73728 next 47
2022-05-26 20:09:47.531847: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e121800 of size 6000128 next 56
2022-05-26 20:09:47.532183: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 70e6da600 of size 155750400 next 7
2022-05-26 20:09:47.532544: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 717b63600 of size 155750400 next 8
2022-05-26 20:09:47.532881: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 720fec600 of size 155750400 next 13
2022-05-26 20:09:47.533209: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 72a475600 of size 155750400 next 12
2022-05-26 20:09:47.533554: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 7338fe600 of size 1661337600 next 11
2022-05-26 20:09:47.533885: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] InUse at 79695e600 of size 1661337600 next 15
2022-05-26 20:09:47.534201: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1083] Free  at 7f99be600 of size 1237588480 next 18446744073709551615
2022-05-26 20:09:47.534585: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1088]      Summary of in-use Chunks by size:
2022-05-26 20:09:47.535048: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 25 Chunks of size 256 totalling 6.2KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.535368: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 1280 totalling 1.2KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.535709: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 3584 totalling 3.5KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.536064: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 36864 totalling 36.0KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.536386: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 39936 totalling 39.0KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.536885: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 55552 totalling 54.2KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.538171: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 2 Chunks of size 73728 totalling 144.0KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.540404: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 73984 totalling 72.2KiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.540821: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 1 Chunks of size 6000128 totalling 5.72MiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.541139: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 3 Chunks of size 155750400 totalling 445.61MiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.541450: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1091] 2 Chunks of size 1661337600 totalling 3.09GiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.541770: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1095] Sum Total of in-use chunks: 3.54GiB
2022-05-26 20:09:47.542088: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1097] total_region_allocated_bytes_: 5190451200 memory_limit_: 5767168000 available bytes: 576716800 curr_region_allocation_bytes_: 11534336000
2022-05-26 20:09:47.542449: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:1103] Stats:
Limit:                      5767168000
InUse:                      3796291584
MaxInUse:                   3968822784
NumAllocs:                         253
MaxAllocSize:               2536791040
Reserved:                            0
PeakReserved:                        0
LargestFreeBlock:                    0

2022-05-26 20:09:47.542854: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc:491] **********__*****************************************************************_______________________
2022-05-26 20:09:47.543195: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1745] OP_REQUIRES failed at conv_ops.cc:684 : RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,32,3120,4160] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\slind\Documents\IT\Development\In development\Deep-Learning-Image-Enhancer-Using-CLAHE-and-Zero-DCE\image-processor.py", line 94, in <module>
    start()
  File "C:\Users\slind\Documents\IT\Development\In development\Deep-Learning-Image-Enhancer-Using-CLAHE-and-Zero-DCE\image-processor.py", line 47, in start
    main()
  File "C:\Users\slind\Documents\IT\Development\In development\Deep-Learning-Image-Enhancer-Using-CLAHE-and-Zero-DCE\image-processor.py", line 57, in main
    (DCE(preprocess(image))).save(outputdir + image.replace(inputdir, ''))
  File "C:\Users\slind\Documents\IT\Development\In development\Deep-Learning-Image-Enhancer-Using-CLAHE-and-Zero-DCE\image-processor.py", line 87, in DCE
    enhanced = dce_model.predict(expanded)
  File "C:\Users\slind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\slind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 54, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.ResourceExhaustedError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'model/conv2d_2/Conv2D' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\slind\Documents\IT\Development\In development\Deep-Learning-Image-Enhancer-Using-CLAHE-and-Zero-DCE\image-processor.py", line 39, in <module>
      dce_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('./model/cast2')
    File "C:\Users\slind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 64, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\slind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\save.py", line 209, in load_model
      return saved_model_load.load(filepath_str, compile, options)
    File "C:\Users\slind\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\saving\saved_model\load.py", line 141, in load
      loaded = tf.__internal__.saved_model.load_partial(
Node: 'model/conv2d_2/Conv2D'
OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,32,3120,4160] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
         [[{{node model/conv2d_2/Conv2D}}]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info. This isn't available when running in Eager mode.
 [Op:__inference_predict_function_2591]
Press any key to continue . . .
```

It says it has 5.7, but doesn't wanna go above3 3.8
Limit:                      5767168000
InUse:                      3796291584
MaxInUse:                   3968822784

Maybe i'm just stupid, pretty new to this :D let me know if you need the code, or if you can tell me based on the error :)

Comment: Without code and more details, we cannot really tell you more than just the error, there is just no free memory to allocate a 1.5GB block. Maybe you should ask yourself, why is my model using so much RAM?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a snippet like this:

`tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=1024)`

And switch out Logical with Physical depending on what you are using.